# Is there an easy way to strip twin and earth cable?

Tags: electrical

It seems whatever method I use I sometimes damage the wire and have to hope I have enough cable to have a 2nd try.

Is there a method that works 100% of the time for someone that is not doing it every day?

---

A possible duplicate has been pointed out, however it talks about 12/10 guage "Romex" rather then the normal 2.5mm twin and earth we have in the UK.

Comment: Are you removing the outer sheath, or stripping the inner wires?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3366/what-is-the-right-way-to-strip-power-wires

Comment: @Tester, I wish to do both, but removing the outer sheath is the harder bit.

Comment: This question has been asked before.  Take a look at the answers to the question I linked to earlier, they should answer your question.

Comment: [2.5mm T&E](http://wiki.diyfaq.org.uk/index.php?title=Cables) is very similar to 12/2 NM (non-metallic) cable.  Romex is a brand name that has become synonymous with NM cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tools which do the job for you. They will probably take a little adjustment when first used, but then they're fine. They are *literally* the easiest way to consistently strip mains cable.

Many years ago my father had a hand-held tool explicitly for stripping Australian 240V household wiring cable. It had two clamps, two blades and a two-part action. The first clamped the cable and made the cuts, the second separated the clamps, neatly stripping the end off the cable.

(I should add that I don't strip cable every day but I learnt how to use a small but very sharp pen knife to strip outer sheaths. A bit time-consuming, but I like doing it that way as it works on any sort of multi-core cable. And the trick to not nipping the conductor is to not cut quite all the way through the insulation: let the stripping effort break the last little bit.)

Answer (score 3):

I love [this little guy](http://www.idealindustries.com/prodDetail.do?prodId=45-025&div=3&l1=wire_strippers&l2=lilripper&l3=45-025) from ideal:

[image: ideal lil ripper stripper]

the tool is a hollow tube. there's a hooked blade centered in the middle so that when you push the cable through the tool, it splits the sheath without damaging the conductors. the v-groove at the end is for stripping the individual conductors.

it took almost no time for me to learn to strip the inner conductors without nicking. and now i can strip without even looking at the wire.

Comment: will it strip the outer sheaths as well?

Comment: Does anyone know if it is sold in the UK and if so what it is called in the UK?

Comment: i don't know where to get one in the UK, but i can confirm that it strips the outer sheath.